# Electrum iOS alternative that can create multisig wallet with other Electrum wallets?

Tags: wallet, electrum, multi-signature, mobile, ios

I want to create a multisig Electrum wallet with two signers: my desktop and my mobile. Since Electrum is not on iOS and I really want to keep using it on my desktop, is there an alternative available for iOS that is able to create multisig wallets together with Electrum?

Answer (score 1):

[Copay](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/copay-bitcoin-wallet/id951330296?mt=8) has multi sig options. First, it will generate you a regular wallet. After initial process is done, you can create new shared (multi sig) wallet or join the existing one.

Comment: Copay + electrum multisig wallet is not possible. I’d like to use electrum on the Desktop (or another advanced wallet that works with hardware wallets).

Comment: have you tried backwards? electrum might accept some 3rd party seeds

Comment: @user1073075 it is better if you don't try to mix and match wallet software. Use copay on both machines.

Comment: I’d be open to switching from Electrum to another wallet that supports hardware devices (like trezor or ledger) but copay doesn’t (anymore).

Comment: @user1073075 then use electrum on an android phone or laptop  in addition to your pc. maybe buy a used desktop for like $40.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems like the only option for me. Too bad they don’t have an iOS wallet...